# UDF in MS SQL Server returning a query starting with "with" cause

Tags: sql-server-2014

This is a perfectly valid SQL Query and works nicely (for e.g.) in `Microsoft SQL Server 2014`:

```
with t as (select 'a' as attr) select * from t
```

it returns `a`, surely one can simplify it and drop the `with` part, but that's not the point, the point is to find out a smallest example that illustrates the need/problem. I can pack part of it as a UDF:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE x(@__employee_id uniqueidentifier)
AS
RETURN (select 'a' as attr);
```

How can I pack a query that has `with` block? My aim is to achieve something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE x (@__employee_id uniqueidentifier)
AS
RETURN (
    with t as (select 'a' as attr) select * from t
);
```

however `sql server` does not like it, firing an error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure x, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you are mixing procedure and function
2. for UDF, your syntax should be

   CREATE or alter function x (@__employee_id uniqueidentifier)
   returns table
   AS
   RETURN (
   with t as (select 'a' as attr)
   select * from t
   );

Comment: very useful post. Is there any way to pack this into a procedure in case the procedure contains multiple statements and changes the database on the way?

Comment: @arthur not sure i understand the question. Can you use CTE in procedure? yes.
ie:
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE x3 (@__employee_id uniqueidentifier)
AS
begin
    ;with t as (select 'a' as attr) select * from t
 ;with t as (select 'a2' as attr) select * from t
 ;with t as (select 'a3' as attr) select * from t
end

Comment: great comment. I saw `;` in many answers before `with` block (that you also use). May I ask why one starts the block with the semicolon?

Comment: @arthur, the purpose of semi-colons is to terminate statements per the ISO SQL standard. Statement terminators are generally not required in T-SQL except when using newer statements like `WITH` which require the preceding statement, if any, must be terminated with a semi-colon. Some folks throw the terminator before the `WITH` in case the previous statement wasn't properly terminated and the lax T-SQL parser allows this. See [this article](https://www.dbdelta.com/always-use-semicolon-statement-terminators/) for more info.

Comment: as stated, by standard, every command should be eneded by ;. This is not usually needed, but with WITH statement, parser has issue so it is prefixed by ;.
Correctly each statement should be suffixed, but old habits die hard.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: this was the reason why I chose procedure to begin with. You got my attention that hacks exist. Can you give an example? (Since I am using procedure you can be sure that I'll not misuse it :-))

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `return` keyword as suggested in [how to return a table from a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604927/how-to-return-a-table-from-a-stored-procedure):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xx (@__employee_id uniqueidentifier)
AS
    with t as (select 'a' as attr) select * from t
```